# How to replace a sentence

Tags: regex, vim, regex-greedy

How to replace the text

input: 
This glass contains 1.5l of milk. But i don't like milk

ouptput: 
Replace_text But i don't like milk

I need to replace text from the beginning to the next full dot. But i don't know what was the sentence.

Comment: do you want to replace the whole line always by the 2nd sentence?

Comment: No, just gave an example.

Comment: then what's the rule?? mish gave an answer, you comment with other examples

Comment: and you have to do it with `:s` command? or other vim editor commands also acceptable? e.g. normal mode commands?

Comment: if i came with other text "This glass contains 1.5l of milk. But i don't like milk. This is an example". if it is in one line, then it will take the last dot. (i think, need to use nongreedy)

Comment: check my answer then, hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

vim has its definition of **sentence**. This you can read `:h sentence`.

For your example, I would do (assume your cursor is at the BOL):

```
c)WAHTEVER
```

The `c)` will remove the 1st sentence and enter INSERT mode.

To do batch replacement, you can record macro or make use of `normal` command.

Answer (score 2):

What about this substitution command?

```
:%s/\(.\{1,}\)\.\(\w*\)/Replace_text\2/g
```

or using character classes (you might need to add special characters etc):

```
([\w\s]+\.\S[\w\s]+)\.(.*)
```

http://regexr.com/3cc0r

Comment: a bit more. if the text is  "This glass contains 1.5l of milk. But i don't like milk. Please check." then it fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

<kbd>^</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

It jumps to first non-blank character, deletes text including `.` and puts you in insert mode so that you can type in `Repace_text`.

If you want to change till the `.`, change <kbd>f</kbd> with <kbd>t</kbd>

You can also make use of text objects. <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> will let you change the sentence.